# set a single value to selected multiple textfields in angular typescript and in html

Tags: angular, typescript, input

I have repeated multiple text boxes and using a checkbox more than one textboxes been selected. In selected textboxes I needed to put same value at a time in angular, typescript.

I had given something like this. In my typescript but not working.

```
    @ViewChildren("textboxes") textboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;

    <div class="liststyle" [hidden]="isSetAggLimit">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let state of AllState">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input #checkboxes type="checkbox" class="form-control" (change)="checkBoxClick(state,'S',$event)"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="p-l-4">{{state.stateCode}}</label> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input #limitValues class="form-control" placeholder="$" type="text" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand your question so please clarify with an example if possible if this is not what you wanted. But one way i could see to do this would be to check if the checkbox has been ticked on and then inject a value into the input with one way data binding.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" #checkbox>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" [value]="checkbox.checked ? 'Your value or a variable if you want 
    to set it on the typescript file' : ''">
</div>
```